# Get a specific value out of a DictionaryList with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary:

```
 var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

With this values:

```
 [0]: {[1, "Person1"]}
 [1]: {[2, "Person2, Person3"]}
 [2]: {[3, "Person4"]}
 [3]: {[4, "Person5"]}
```

And when i use a "foreach" to get the values with "id" 2 i get as result "Person2, Person3".

```
foreach (var test in dict)
{
    if (test.Key == 2)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test.Value);
}
```

But when i use this LINQ line:

```
 Person = dict.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == s.Person.ID).Value.ToString(),
```

I get this error:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator.

I tried several things but nothing seems to work, so any ideas?

EDIT

I use this to show output on my page:

```
 DataSelectionQuery = p => new
          {
              p.ID,
              p.FirstName,
              p.LastName,
              TEST = dict.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == p.ID).Value.ToString(),
          };

 public Expression<Func<LinqClass, object>> DataSelectionQuery { get; set; }
```

And here is where it trows the error:

```
 var results = query.Select(DataSelectionQuery).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL? Because your example says you use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: You can get data using `var value = dict[s.Person.ID]`. If you can to check if key exists you can use `dict.ContainsKey(s.Person.ID)`

Comment: Where does `s` comes from in `s.Person.ID`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel s comes from "DataSelectionQuery = s => new"

Comment: using LINQ over a dictionary is quite useless. Why making the collection a dictionary in the first place if it's to use the slow search of LINQ ?

Comment: @Franck becouse i had to merge the object with the same id, see object with id = 2

Comment: i still don't see the need for LINQ `dict[2] = dict[2] + ", person 3";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
 Person = string.Join(", ", PersonsQuery.Where(q => q.ID == s.ID).Select(q => q.PersonInformation))
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use this kind of expressions inside `Linq to SQL` as they cannot be translated to `SQL query`
Use `.ToList()` at the end of your query, then use `Linq to objects` to complete your entity with values from Dictionary

For example when you have code like:

```
var result = from x in table
  select new Entity
  {
      Id = x.Id,
      Sth = x.Sth,
      Person = dict.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == s.Person.ID).Value.ToString()
  };
```

You need to change it to something like this:

```
var result = (from x in table
  select new { x.Id, x.Sth, x.PersonId }) // LINQ To SQL part
  .ToList() // get query results
  .Select(x => new Entity
  {
      Id = x.Id,
      Sth = x.Sth,
      Person = dict.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == x.PersonId).Value.ToString()
  }; // this part will be executed with Linq to objects
```

Please provide the full source code if you need more detailed help

---

Ok, so your "SelectionQuery" needs to be simple enough to translate into SQL query and should look like this:

```
 DataSelectionQuery = p => new
          {
              p.ID,
              p.FirstName,
              p.LastName
          };
```

And the other part should look like this:

```
 var results = query.Select(DataSelectionQuery).ToList()
    .Select(p => new
    {
        p.ID,
        p.FirstName,
        p.LastName,
        TEST = dict.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == p.ID).Value.ToString()
    });
```

Alernatively you can create your own class which will contain the Dictionary and will translate the ID into `TEST` on the getter action

Comment: @Adassko LINQ to objects?

Comment: @Adassko Hmm doesn't work, why does this work "Test = dict.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == 2).Value," and this not "Test = dict.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == p.ID).Value,"